# How to change pagination text "Next" "Previous" to Icon or arrow in AG-Grid pagination

Tags: reactjs, pagination, ag-grid

I am using AG-Grid want to change pagination button text to icon or arrows Please help me for same. Please check attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Please show us the example, that you have tried. Did you try adding icons to by overriding the class specified by ag-grid?

Comment: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-pagination/#custom-pagination-controls

Comment: @pawel Its not the code of ag-grid, its the code that the OP should have tried before asking a question. For example: did he override the css of the button?

Answer (score 2):

A way to achieve what you need, but with a little bit more work involved, is to hide the built-in pagination control completely by setting "suppressPaginationPanel" in grid options to true. Then you need to add buttons and text "Page … of …". Buttons should call grid api functions like paginationGoToNextPage() etc., and the text you can generate using functions like paginationGetCurrentPage(). All details you will find at https://ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-pagination/?framework=all#gsc.tab=0

Comment: I have added  icons  by overriding the CSS classes. My problem get resolved.Thanks All for help

Comment: @NitinShinde I'm facing the same issue too, can you please share how to overide css

Comment: @Nitin can you please share the  steps to override  CSS as I am also  facing same issue